# Is "weightage" an English word?

Tags: nouns, british-english, dialects, is-it-a-word, subcontinental-english

Is *weightage* an English word?

We use it a lot in India, but I couldn't find it in my Oxford Dictionary.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to find it in the Collins English Dictionary, which marks it as *Indian*:

> **weightage** *chiefly (Indian)* another name for *weighting*

The [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) has 259 cites for *weighting*, but not a single one for *weightage*.

Comment: So, yes. It is an English word, but only an Indian English word.

Comment: it is used in the sense relative importance, as in "we dont give much weightage to looks" or "career has a higher weightage than marriage"... also see http://www.indianexpress.com/news/no-weightage-for-marks-iit-admission-board/966062/, http://www.simplylearnt.com/topic-weightage/IIT-JEE, http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/WEIGHTAGE, so what could be the appropriate word to use in place of weightage.

Comment: I get the feeling that *weightage* is an Indian coinage. Although useful, the question remains of just how many non-Indians would actually understand it. I think it’s better not to use it when addressing non-Indians.

Comment: @BinaryNights You should just use *weight* there.

Comment: The term is also known (and used) in Singapore. It is typically used in exam rubrics: 'this question has a weightage of 30%'. It would be formulated differently, say in BrE, where you might say, 'this question carries 30% of the marks'.

Comment: @Peter Or just *weight*.

Answer (score 3):

Weightage is not a word used in American or British English. For the example you give, AmEng academics use the verb *to be weighted*.

> The entrance test is weighted 30% of your final grade.

Answer (score 2):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/weightage) has included the word 'weightage' and mentioned it as 'Indian English' origin. The meaning given is:

> (noun) the value or importance of something when compared with another thing.
>   *The entrance test carries 40 percent weightage in the final result.*